# Sum max consecutive cells if negative

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]

Hi, i have a little problem, i have column A(2:11) with random positive and negative numbers and i need a formula for finding the highest sum of consecutive negative numbers, in this case A7, A8, A9 with sum = -6.

It doesn't matter how many negative cells are, i need to find the highest sum of consecutive ones from that column.

Comment: So if cell `A4` was `-1` would your sum be `-6` or `-12`?

Comment: If A4 was -1, would be the same -6, if was -3, my sum would be -8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write `=A2` in Cell `C2`.
2. In Cell `C3` write this Formula & Drag down 
   till it's needed.

   `=IF(SIGN(A3)=SIGN(A2),C2+A3,A3)`
3. Write this Formula in Cell `C13`.

`=Min(C2:C11)`

*You get **`-6`** as Sum of Max consecutive cell value if Negative.*

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: I checked it, but i can't give an upvote, seems i'm a new user and i can't give right now, anyway i'm glad i found a nice community

Comment: Glad to help @Edward,, keep asking,, ☺

Answer (score 2):

First, add a formula, one cell to the right of the data range on the first row with data (which we will assume here will be *A2*), **=IF(*A2*<0,*A2*+B1,0)** which will look at the cell to the left and, if negative, add it to the value of the cell above. Copy it, and paste it down into Column B, for every line where you have data in Column A.

Below the end of the cells of Column B, please add a new cell (here shown in B13) with the formula, **=MIN(B2:B11)**

[image: An illustration of the result]